# How to preg_match_all only whats in the body

Tags: php, regex, web-crawler

So I have :

```
function crawl( $url ){
   $content = @file_get_contents( $url );
   if( $content === FALSE) {
       echo "<br/> Not working " . $url;
       return;
   }

   $content = strtolower( $content );

   preg_match_all( '/http:\/\/[^ "\']+/', $content , $links );

   foreach( $links[0] as $crawled ){
       sleep( 1 );

       crawl( $crawled );
   }
}
```

I want it to go through the site I give it ($url), and search for all the links in it, kind of like a web crawler, and it goes through the first site get it gets links that don't go anywhere cuz they're css links or js or something that isn't a page. How can I fix it to only get links in the body tags or actual links?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, you are already checking the false value!

Comment: Yea but its giving me links that don't work because they're linking to the css pages or something inside the server, I need to know how to get links inside the body tags so that they lead to pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a crude way of trimming the content to only what is within the body tags before applying the regex:

```
$content = strtolower( $content );
// Added code below...
$bodyStartPos = strpos( $content , "<body>" );
$bodyEndPos = strpos( $content , "</body>" );
$content = substr( $content, $bodyStartPos, $bodyEndPos - $bodyStartPos );
```

There's more detail you could add such as allowing whitespace in tags, adding the length of the tag to the start position, ensuring end tag is after start tag, ignoring tags in quotes etc. But this should be rough and ready enough to get you started...